# CSS Flexible Sticky Header which may Grow and Pushes Below Items Down

Tags: html, css, angular, sticky-footer

I am trying to create a Sticky Header, where the Sticker Header can grow (Green Box), if user chooses more documents in left grid (not pictured).

Everything else should be push downed correspondingly (in the blue box).
Not sure how to do this, since all the resources say sticky header `position:fixed` and body `padding-top`  is at set amount.

Error - Right now the blue sticky header, is eating over the Green box, as more document titles are added.

There are 3 boxes below, Black is overall container, Green is top Sticky Header, and Blue is Body.

Sticky header should hold, while user scrolls down to read long body.

Alternative: Currently using Javascript below, wonder if there is way to conduct strictly with CSS, flexbox,  no Js.

```
document.getElementById("bluebox-body-id").style.paddingTop = (50 * numberOfDocuments).toString()+ "px";
```

[image]

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp

Utilizing Angular framework, just fyi ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will get resolved if you change the position property.

Change it to sticky: `position:sticky`

Comment: Hi, the header was growing when adding more documents, without eating the body, however when I scrolled down, the sticky header was not holding

Comment: Is it possible for you to replicate the issue ? Its working fine in w3school.

Comment: can you send me a link for w3 school?

Comment: I edited the first fiddle of the URL shared by you. Check this URL - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_menu

Comment: this will not work in my growing header, because they said margin top to a specific value .main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}

Comment: is it possible for you to replicate your issue? in stackblitz or jsfiddle ?

Comment: unfortunately working in corporate environment, its just basically 3 boxes, in question picture above,

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be an issue with default html/css. I think there might be some specific css that is causing this effect. You could play around with the css values to figure out what is causing this.

In this example I recreated the result you seek. Please have a look.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: cyan;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.container__top {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: green;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container__bottom {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <section class="container__top">
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
      <li>d</li>
      <li>e</li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section class="container__bottom">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
  </section>



</div>
```

Comment: this is not working, as it needs to be a scrollable full page answer, I tried expanding to full page